# Is it possible to use MQ Client with a web app installed in an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a web app running on Windows Server but we need to migrate it to an Azure App Service.

Our web app uses MQ Client service to connect with certain transaction services, but it is not possible to install other services on the Azure App Service except for the web app.

Is there a way to use MQ Client in Azure?

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to use MQ Client in Azure?

As Azure WebApp is a [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). Install MQ client is not supported on the Azure WebApp service.

If [Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/overview) is acceptable, I recommand that you could use Azure VM to instead of Azure WebApp service in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, in our case a virtual machine is not a possibility.